# Issues displaying data in node js , ejs

Tags: node.js, api, express, ejs, fetch-api

I am a newbie
i have been trying to fetch data from an API using node js express and ejs.
My problem is that i cannot display the data in my page.
looks like something is wrong with the way that i render the data . when i console.log my response, i have access to it but it does not seem to want to display
can you help me plz.

I tried to fetch the data like this :

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
  exports.allCarte = async (req, res) => {
 
fetch('https://pokeapi-enoki.netlify.app/')
  .then((response) => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
    }

    return response.json();
   
  })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response)
   res.render("../views/home",{
    response
   })
  });

}
```

and here is what I did in the home.ejs :

```
<body>
        <main>
         
          <ul>
            <% for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {%>
             
              <li><%=response[i].name %></li>
              
             
            <% } %>
            <h1>Hi, there!</h1>
          
      
           
          </ul>
        </main>
 
    
<
```

Comment: You said: _i cannot display the data in my page. looks like something is wrong_  But what actually happens?  How do you know something is wrong?

Comment: i can access the data through console.log however on my localhost i just have a blank page .

Comment: What do your browser debugging tools tell you?  Did the server respond properly (200 OK?  Correct content type, etc?) (if you look at the response in the browser).  How "blank" is it?  Does the browser show an error in the console?

Comment: There is no Error . the function is working fine and the route to from the controller to the view  is also working .

Comment: the data just won't appears like there is something missing in the fucntion . i dont know what it is

Comment: i know the route is working fine because if i change the response into another name then i have an error about "such other name is  not defined

Comment: Can you render trivial static output?  `<html><body>hello</body></html>`

Comment: yes i can. there is a h1 and it displays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a look at results from the `https://pokeapi-enoki.netlify.app/` API, it is structured something like this:

```json
{
  "pokemons": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "germignon",
       ...    
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "kaiminus",
      ...
```

...which means the array of interest is `response.pokemons` not just `response`.

Your **home.ejs** should be changed like this:

```js
  <% for(var i = 0; i < response.pokemons.length; i++) {%>
    <li><%=response.pokemons[i].name %></li>
  <% } %>
```